SAP btp Automation pilot
I have imported a catalog (in JSON format) from GitHub into my project (BTP AUTOMATION PILOT). I need to trigger a specific command that requires a service key, but I am unsure how to find or create this service key. Additionally, I am not certain about the value that needs to be entered for the service key.
Can you please provide detailed steps on:
How to find or create a service key for the imported catalog?
What value should be entered for the service key to successfully trigger the command?
